# Why doesn't my code for checking if a word is a palindrome work?

Tags: c

So I'm trying to make a code that checks if a word is a palindrome. So, I reversed the user inputted word and checks if the words are equal. However, it always returns "Not equal". Can someone be kind enough to explain why this doesn't work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRING_LENGTH 200


int main() {
    char s[STRING_LENGTH] = {0}; 

    fgets(s, STRING_LENGTH, stdin); 
    int Ordlengde = strlen(s) - 1;


    printf("The word contains %i letters", Ordlengde); 

    int i;
    char palindrom[STRING_LENGTH];
    int x = 0;


    for (i = Ordlengde; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        palindrom[x++] = s[i];
    }

    int Ordlengde1 = strlen(palindrom) - 1;
    printf("The word contains %i letters", Ordlengde);


    printf("\nThe word reversed is %s", palindrom);
    printf("%s",s);
    if (strcmp(s , palindrom) == 0)
        printf("are equal\n");
    else
        printf("are not equal \n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you subtract 1 from the return value of strlen?

Comment: You need to null terminate the string you're building in `palindrom[]`.

Comment: @bruceg I suspect it's stripping off the trailing newline character.

Comment: There are several problems with this code.  `palindrom` is not being terminated with a `'\0'` character.  The first character being copied into `palindrom` is the `'\0'` character from `s`, which makes no sense.  And `s` isn't properly terminated, since the `\n` is still present before the `\0`.

Comment: Why copy and reverse the string when you could simply compare the 1st and last characters, the 2nd and penultimate characters, etc. in a simple loop?

Comment: fix like [this](https://ideone.com/T9wwvr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem was failing to remove the trailing newline. It sometimes helps to quote your output for easy recognition of non-printing character problems like `tabs`, `newlines`, etc.. Doing so immediately reveals the problem. (**note:** where the quotes end up with your original logic)

```
$ ./bin/palindrome
foo
The word contains 3 lettersThe word contains 3 letters
The word reversed is '
oof' <-> 'foo
' (original) are not equal
```

(you are comparing `\noof` with `foo\n` which was failing)

Correcting the newline removal and tidying things up a bit, your logic for the reversal and check works fine, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRING_LENGTH 200

int main() {

    int x = 0, Ordlengde;
    char s[STRING_LENGTH] = "",
        palindrom[STRING_LENGTH] = ""; 

    printf ("enter a word: ");
    if (!fgets (s, STRING_LENGTH, stdin)) { /* VALIDATE INPUT */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input - EOF.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    Ordlengde = strlen(s) - 1;
    if (s[Ordlengde] == '\n')               /* check/remove '\n' */
        s[Ordlengde] = 0;

    while (Ordlengde--)                     /* reverse s */
        palindrom[x++] = s[Ordlengde];

    printf ("\noriginal: '%s'\nreversed: '%s' - ", s, palindrom);

    if (strcmp(s , palindrom) == 0)         /* compare */
        printf("is a palindrom\n");
    else
        printf("is not a palindrom\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/palindrome
enter a word: foo

original: 'foo'
reversed: 'oof' - is not a palindrom

$ ./bin/palindrome
enter a word: foof

original: 'foof'
reversed: 'foof' - is a palindrom
```

A couple of final notes. First, if you are expecting user input, then prompt for it. Otherwise, you leave the user looking at a blinking cursor on the console -- wondering if the program is hung. Sure, you know you need to enter a word, but thing about someone else running your code for the first time. Nothing special is needed, just a simply prompt:

```
printf ("enter a word: ");
```

Next, I would recommend the "traditional" check with the full length of the string minus 1. Why? What if the string was 201 characters long? There would be no new line at the end... That's why the traditional check below will preserve the original length until you confirm there is a `newline` to trim:

```
Ordlengde = strlen(s);
if (Ordlengde && s[Ordlengde - 1] == '\n')  /* remove '\n' */
    s[--Ordlengde] = 0;
```

Keep at it and good luck with your coding.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the thorough  explanation. I appreciate it!

Comment: Sure, glad to help. I added a few notes to the end of the answer for you.

Comment: at `if (Ordlengde && s[Ordlengde] == '\n')` : `Ordlengde &&`  seems to be an almost meaningless guard.

Comment: If it is the empty string you don't want `s[0 - 1]`. (but yes, I get your point)

Comment: Please be aware that it will also be executed when `Ordlengde` becomes `-1`. Also When only newline is entered, newline are not deleted.

Comment: Yes, but if it is simply a single newline -- it's a palindrome anyway `:)` I'll tweak it.

Comment: Allowing newline characters as palindrome is incompatible with other processing. 
And the display is disturbed. `:D`

Comment: Hah! You are correct again. ..."*I always wondered where those two extra lines were coming from...*"